# Reply/ReplyAll to a particular Outlook mail using C#

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, office-interop, mailitem

I want to send a reply to say a particular mail from my Outlook mailBox.
I intend to find the mail by searching the mailbox using the subject/body/sender and then reply to the found mail.
I have succeeded in searching the mail from the mailbox using C#, but i'm not able to reply to the mail.

And also if i use  the reply will it be the exact replica of the action performed in outlook i.e. if replied on a mail, will the subject be added with RE: or we need to manually append the text to subject?

Please spare my Ignorance

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code is an extract

Lets assume you've picked your item, here I picked one by a number..

```
MailItem m = objFolder.Items[t];
m.ReplyAll();
```

This effectively hits "ReplyAll" and fills all the things in as if outlook did it..(because it did) eg, add stuff to the body.. hit send.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But there is no reply generated after this.It is just executing the command but nothing is happening

Comment: Did you do send after?

Comment: If you want the reply to be shown, add myReply = m.ReplyAll(); myReply.Display();

Answer (score 0):

Goutham gauti its right. All changes that you make in your mail item will be response. But if you want more information you can read this article on CodeProject:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1106804/Create-and-send-an-email-reply-in-Csharp-VB-NET

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ReplyToMail(Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
{
  //mailItem is the mail you wand to reply to
   Outlook.MailItem replyMail = mailItem.Reply();
  //you can use replyAll insted
   replyMail.Body = "the mail body text";
   ((Outlook._MailItem)replyMail).Send();
}
```